# SlickGrid checkbox row selectors in 1.4.3

Tags: javascript, checkbox, slickgrid

I'm trying to get the Checkbox row selectors example to run in my project.

http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-checkbox-row-select.html

I use that code, except for the slick.core.js which does not seem to be used in 1.4.3. When I run, I get :

"onSelectedRangesChanged": new Slick.Event() is not a constructor

Which leads me to believe I am missing an important script, but I could not find an updated example in the 1.4.3 branch for the checkbox selectors. I can comment out the line that causes the error (it comes from slick.rowselectionmodel.js), but that leads to further errors.

Has anyone had more luck than I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work on 1.4.3.  It relies on new features added to 2.0.  In particular, Slick.Event is defined in slick.core.js and is a core part of 2.0.

Comment: It's pretty close code-wise, but on a bit of a temporary pause as I ramp up at the new job.